# Is this memory compatible with my laptop?

Tags: memory

Here are my laptop specs:  HP G-62.

CPU-Z has the following for my **current** memory specs:

***DDR3 PC3-10700H (667 MHz)***

I am looking to throw some more RAM in this laptop.  <s>I have found [this memory (Newegg)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148276&Tpk=N82E16820148276) and I'd like to verify I can put this in my laptop.  Here are the specs of the **new** memory:</s>

***DDR3 1066 (PC3 8500)***

My question is, will this memory be compatibile and "work" in my laptop?  Thanks in advance!!

## Update

After the pointer from Simon, the memory now in question to purchase can be found [here (Newegg)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148493).  The specs for this memory are as follows:

***DDR3 1333 (PC3 10600)***

Will this RAM work in my laptop?

Comment: Which HP G-62 do you have? That's a series including a variety of very different laptops.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How can I find out which one I have??  Through the OS?  I don't see anything on the actual physical laptop.

Comment: If all else fails, the Free (Home) version of [SiW](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.php) will tell you, under the `Motherboard` tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new memory has a significantly lower speed than your current one. You will want PC3-10600+. PC3-8500 is several years old now

Comment: +1 great pointer.  Please see the edit of my question.  Will *that* memory in my update work in my laptop?

Comment: What exactly is 10700H?  I can't seem to find any specs on that.  Is that basically PC3-8500 with dual channel?  Just curious.  Hopefully the updated memory will work in my laptop.  Let me know!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that you're already looking at Crucial memory, you can use Crucial's Memory Advisor Tool to check compatibility with most brand-name computers: http://www.crucial.com. Generally speaking, the higher the number in PC3-#####, the better the performance...but on the other hand, you probably wouldn't notice the performance difference in most situations.

Comment: @rob so the PC3 10600 is fine for me then?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. If you're still uneasy about buying it, just use Crucial's Memory Advisor or System Scanner available on their homepage. It will give you a list of memory modules/kits that are "guaranteed" to be compatible.